# Facebook Messenger Platform - Detect user typing

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

When developing bots, it's common practice to show typing indicator to user, while bot is working on background, but is it possible to detect opposite situation: whether USER is typing or idle? I could not find any info in docs or google. Does anybody know how to achieve that?

Comment: I don't think there is an option for this right now. Any reason you would want to know that?

Comment: I'm trying to combine several messages sent separately but expressing single message like "hi" "how are" "you" and only than triggering text processing. So my idea was to check if after receiving first message, user is still typing and if yes, wait for more (actually I'm going to use several indicators, but this is important one) , if no, process input.

Comment: It would be really useful. I can think of cases when a user sends first message "hello", followed by a question "is anyone there?" and the bot would start reacting too early.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This currently can't be done.

You can only show the user that you are typing.

```
"typing_on" and "typing_off" for the sender_action.
```

Answer (score -1):

I made it using twisted way,
Using image processing i take screenshot and see if he is typing or not using python sc