# Facebook messenger bot - Detect user typing

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

I am interested in capturing the event of the user typing in my bot through the DirectLine API (REST).

[Botframework documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Bot-Framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-activities) says this is possible: [...] *typing    Indicates that the user or bot on the other end of the conversation is compiling a response* [...]

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43829148/facebook-messenger-platform-detect-user-typing) says Facebook Messenger does not support it (2017).

Perhaps some channels (Slack, Skype...) might support this, others don't (Facebook).

Perhaps I just didn't find the right place in documentation to make it work, if so, any link I can follow?

Any representative of either Azure / Facebook who can provide insight about this being in the roadmap and ETA?

Thanks in advance for the answers!!!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a limitation as of Feb 2018.

Confirmed for Facebook Messenger and Slack by now.

I will take @oflahero and mine own experience + no answers on these threads (with MS guys having tagged it) as a NO, this cannot be done:

- [Github for Botbuilder](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4167)
- [Gitter for Botbuilder](https://gitter.im/Microsoft/BotBuilder)
- [Github Botframework documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-framework-docs/issues/108)

No confirmation about it being in roadmap/ETA.

[Edit]: Alive conversation at Botframework Github [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4167).

Answer (score 0):

Currently BotFramework works by sending whole messages (to MessageController's 'Post' method if using C#, for example), once the user hits send/return. There's no magic AJAX going on in the background sending individual keystroke info to the bot, unfortunately.

However, there is such a value in the ActivityTypes enum called 'Typing'. This is typically used by the bot to send an 'I'm typing' indicator to the user, if you want to buy time. This is what the doc you're referring to is talking about:

```
        var msg = context.MakeMessage();
        msg.Text = string.Empty;
        msg.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
        await context.PostAsync(msg);
```

But, for the user typing TO the bot - the question is, does your channel support sending an activity of type ActivityTypes.Typing to the bot? Try finding out by having a look at the HandleSystemMessage method in your MessagesController and add some handler code. The boilerplate handles a selection of the enum values, including Typing (but currently does nothing):

```
        ....
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            // Handle knowing that the user is typing
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @olflahero.

I have done something equivalent to what you suggest and I didn't see any request coming of typing type.

Being in the documentation, I would expect at least some channel to support it, can someone confirm having seen and processed typing requests coming from the user side? If so, can you please share your experience?


I have found this: http://www.garypretty.co.uk/2016/07/18/bot-framework-typing-activity-let-users-know-your-bot-is-responding/ where I see C#? snippet to process typing event...

Is this something that worked in the past, not now?

Comment: The Webchat channel contains a way to send Typing from user to bot when you look at the code. For other channels, it's difficult to know exactly the capabilities

Comment: Yes, I can confirm Facebook Messenger doesn't support the user-to-bot typing activity (I'm using Messenger for my own project at the moment.) My assumption is that the bot team included it in the spec with a view to having compatible channels support it if they could. Future-proofing I suppose.